# can android kill a foreground activity?

Tags: android

I know that android SO can kill activities and process if it needs memory.

Question 1:
Can android kill an activity if it is in foreground?

Question 2:
Can android kill the activity's process if the activity is in foreground?

Comment: "I know that android SO can kill activities and process if it needs memory" -- Android does not "kill" activities in response to memory pressure. This is a common misconception, courtesy of some poor wording in the Android documentation. I wrote [a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html) about 40 months ago to try to clear that up.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you for the link I will read it. So the correct phrase is: "the android restarts the activity and kill the process?"

Comment: Android terminates processes to free up system RAM for use by other processes. If, through something like the recent-tasks list, the user goes back to your app, Android will fork a fresh process for you and will create a new instance of the first activity that the user needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android [processes and application lifecycle document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) states that:

> **foreground process**
>
> ...
>
> There will only ever be a few such processes in the system, and these
> will only be killed as a last resort if memory is so low that not even
> these processes can continue to run. Generally, at this point, the
> device has reached a memory paging state, so this action is required
> in order to keep the user interface responsive.

Which means your activity (and therefore process) can be killed but only under extreme memory conditions and as a last resort. Empty processes, background processes, service processes and visible processes will all be killed before your process will be killed so it's **extremely** unlikely this will ever happen but the possibility is there if leaving your application open will lead to system instability.

Comment: "so it's extremely unlikely this will ever happen" In my case is common.

Comment: @iberck at least with Android N it seems like Android will sometimes happily (grr) kill my foregrounded Service process simply because the screen has been off for a few hours, totally wrecking my logger!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Yes.

Answer 2: Explain better please.

Resume: You can get all running processes and kill those with the specified pid

Add 2 permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

Later use this code to get PID and later kill process

```
ArrayList<Integer> pids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ActivityManager  manager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
{
    if (pids.contains(process.pid))
    {
        // Ends the app
        manager.restartPackage(process.processName);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK OP's question was in relation to an application's lifecycle and Android's memory management, not how he can kill applications himself.

Answer (score 0):

Every process is assigned an OOM score. The score depends on the process class and usually there are other processes to kill before Android OOM killer starts considering foreground processes. But, there are other classes with higher priority than foreground and it is entirely possible that someone (vendor?) stuffed the device with so many memory-hungry persistent processes that OOM has to kill some of the foreground class. Though I would say it is highly unlikely. What does "dumpsys meminfo" say?